# Subversion permissions problem

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, svn, mod-dav-svn

I have set up a subversion server through Apache http (mod_dav_svn).  I created a Subversion project at /usr/local/svn.  I can check out the project via svn co http://host/svn.  However, when I try to commit, I get this error:

```
svn: Can't create directory '/usr/local/svn/db/transactions/0-1.txn': Permission denied.
```

I tried changing the owner and permissions of /usr/local/svn (the repository) as follows:

```
chown -R apache.apache /usr/local/svn
chmod -R g-w /usr/local/svn
```

Unfortunately this does not solve the problem.  Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/114852/cannot-commit-to-svn-repository-via-http).

Answer (score 1):

I have almost the same setup and to make this work for all the application developers I used the following permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data
```

my www-data user/group = your apache user/group

I also added the applications developers to the group www-data.

By the way, this is in my apache conf file (this keeps things more secure):

```
  <Location /somesite>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/www/svn/somesite
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Subversion Repository"
     AuthUserFile /home/www/svn/.htpasswd
     <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user               
     </Limit>
  </Location>
```

Test first that you can commit locally on your server and then remotely.